# RPG style collision boundary

Tags: c#, xna, collision

i'm working on a small RPG game, and what i currently have is:

*Character with animation and basic collision;
*A 32x32 box which i test the collision on;

And thats all for now..xD

My character is 32xPixels wide, and 48xPixels tall, 32x38.

And i have Two rectangles, `playerRectangle`(for collision and movement);
And `rectangleAnimation`, for the character animation.

Well, my question is, how do i make a collision rectangle that only covers half of the character? Right now my rectangle is 32x48, so how do i make it 32x24, **WITHOUT** cropping the image?

It gives the illusion of being infront of something, for example a rock, or a tree.

I tried to make a seperate sprite, which is 32x24 and made a rectangle of it and drew two sprites in my player class, but that didn't work...

And my last question, should i make a seperate class, like `CollisionHandler.cs` for all my solid things, like walls, and boxes?

Here's my movement code for the player(without attempting to make a diffrent sized rectangle):

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{ 
    playerRectangle.X -= playerSpeed; 
    movingLeft = true;
    movingRight = false; 
}    
else if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{ 
    playerRectangle.X += playerSpeed; 
    movingRight = true; 
    movingLeft = false; 
}

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{ 
    playerRectangle.Y -= playerSpeed; 
    movingUp = true;
    movingDown = false;
}
else if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{ 
    playerRectangle.Y += playerSpeed; 
    movingDown = true; 
    movingUp = false; 
}
```

(I'm sorry that the code looks messy, i'm new to this site and i don't know how to structure it :/)

And my collision check(Which is in Game1.cs):

```
if(isColliding())
{
    if (player.movingRight)
    {
        player.playerRectangle.X -= player.playerSpeed;
    }
    else if (player.movingLeft)
    {
        player.playerRectangle.X += player.playerSpeed;
    }

    if (player.movingUp)
    {
        player.playerRectangle.Y += player.playerSpeed;
    }
    else if(player.movingDown)
    {
        player.playerRectangle.Y -= player.playerSpeed;
    }
}
```

I have a method in `Game1.cs` that's called "isColliding", which checks for collision in another class rectangle and my playerRectangle..

I'm sorry this is so long, but thank you in advance, and tell me if you need to know something else :)

Comment: omg, please store `isColliding` value into another variable and NOT call it 4 times... And use `else` if the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Can you post isColliding() code?

Comment: @Dariusz or better yet, do something like if (IsColliding()) { // additional logic here }

Comment: create `boundingBox` property of every sprite separated, because it looks that `playerRectangle` you use to move sprites. then you can freely edit `boundingBox` by adding offsets and use that to check collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vector2.Distance(playerPosition, objectToCheck);

```
if(Vector2.Distance(playerPosition,objectToCheck < player.rectangle.width/2){
 //If  the player is too close to the object you wish to check
 //Do something...
}
```

For the collisions, i'd just check in your player's update method whether or not 'he' has collided with anything - using vector.distance^^

You're movement logic is bad:

You should be using velocity.

var velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
var moveSpeed = 5; //Whatever you want

```
if(player presses right){
   velocity.X += moveSpeed;
}
if(player presses up){
   velocity.y += moveSpeed;
}
```

this.position += velocity * Gametime.elapsedGametime; << Think Gametime is correct...

Var origin = new vector2(rectangle.width /2, rectangle.height/2); This will set the origin of the sprite to the center of the rectangle, as opposed to the top left.

Say we have two rectangles both 50x50... to check for a collision between the two you'd do:

```
if(Vector2.Distance(rectangle1.position, rectangle2.position < rectangle1.width/2){

    //If the distance between the two rectangles (from the middle of the rectangle(the       origin we just set is less than then half of the width of the rectangle... we have a collision.
}
```

Haven't used XNA in a few months, so you might have to update the origin in the update method of your classes...

Comment: I don't think it will work for player.rectangle.width != player.rectangle.height

Comment: Now my characters moves with stop D:
And also the collision isn't working :/
What should i do to fix it?

Comment: Update(){
   if(press right...){
       velocity.x += moveSpeed;
     }
    ....

   playerPosition += velocity;
   velocity = Vector2.Zero;
}

There should be no problem with that movement logic...?

Ok so say we have two rectangles, both with width and height set to 50 (so they're squares)

To detect a collision between the two you would do something like...

       if(Vector2.Distance(rectangle1.Origin, rectangle2.Origin <                 rectangle1.Width /2){

    //There's a collision
}

You'll want to set the origin of each sprite to a new vector(height/2,width/2);

Comment: If(Vector2.Distance(circle1,circle2) > circle1.radius) Will work just fine.

Comment: Of course it will. What won't work (properly) is rectangle1.width/2 when width != height - character will collide vertically or horizontally depending on higher value. I may have written last comment wrong - it won't work for any rectangle that's not a square ;)

Comment: I got the movement working, but i canno to the `if(Vector2.Distance(player.playerRectangle, box.rectangle < player.playerRectangle.Width / 2))`, it says: **Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle' and 'int'**.... :/

Comment: if(Vector2.Distance(playerPosition,objectToCheck) < player.rectangle.width/2) - missing one closing bracket

Comment: Yeah I realized after I posted the comment you were referring to!

Comment: @QuackTheDuck in your if you have player.playerRectangle - where you should have player.playerRectangle.Position. Likewise with the box.rectangle.position

Comment: @QuackTheDuck I seriously recommend you brush up on some trigonometry and geometry, making games will make much more sense if you have a keen grasp on the math. KhanAcademy is a good resource to check out.

Answer (score 2):

i will write from my head... add this into your sprite class, it will be universal

```
public Rectangle BoundingBox
{
 get { return new Rectangle((int)Position.X + offsetX, (int)Position.Y + offsetY, Texture.Width - offsetWidth, Texture.Height - offsetWidth); }
}
```

simply changing `offsetX`, `offsetY`, `offsetWidth`, `offSetHeight` you can adjust collision box. so if you wish collision on top left corner for 5x5 pixels. then `offsetX=0`, `offestY=0`, `offsetWidth=5`, `offsetHeight=5`

and collide code

```
foreach (Sprite brick in bricklist)
{
   if (player.BoundingBox.Intersects(brick.BoundingBox))
   {
       // do some stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: So this is my playerRectangle:
`playerRectangle = new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y + 24,
            frameWidth - 5, frameHeight - 5);`
But my character still get's smaller D:  I have two rectangles, rectangleAnimation as my source, and playerRectangle as destRectangle.  Should i do something diffrent on them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the height of the player rectangle by half, all you do is just divide the playerRectangle.Y value by 2.

Comment: How do i do that for only the playerRectangle.Y?

Comment: player.PlayerRectangle.Y / 2